# jQuery popup window timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

So I add a jQuery popup to a submit button in ASP.net MVC4.

```
$('#submitrequestbutton').click(function (e) {
   $('#popup').bPopup();
});
```

That works like a charm. However, it goes away after a millisecond. How do I keep it open until the user clicks close, so it doesn't post back before the user has a chance to read the contents?

I'm using http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

**EDIT**
Alternatively, if I could just keep the popup open for a few seconds, that would work too.

Comment: Is the button by any chance an anchor link? If it is you need to prevent it from refreshing the page by doing e.preventDefault(); right before your pop up call

Comment: I actually just want the pop up to display, then when the user clicks 'Close', then the form is submitted to the database. @jayaguilar

Comment: @duckmike - pls answer jayaguitar's question.

Comment: not sure I'm following when you say click the "close" button, do you mean the browser close button or is there a close button. The example you are giving does not really showcase what you're trying to do in that case...

Comment: @ArvindSridharan the button isn't in an anchor link. It's a standard input button. <input type="submit" id="submitrequestbutton" value="Send request" />

Comment: @jayaguilar I'm sorry, I mean when they click the close button on the pop up.

Comment: @jayaguilar is the button in a form?

Comment: @jayaguilar yes it's in a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hope this works for you

```
$('#submitrequestbutton').click(function (e) {
$('#popup').bPopup({
easing: 'easeOutBack', //uses jQuery easing plugin
            speed: 450,
    });
});
```

Check out this link for more info http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/